# app engine endpoint return 503 error while listing all the entities

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I am trying to get list of all my entities from the data store in app engine. i created my class and generate the app engine endpoint class. All the apis seems to work except the list all my entities. It returns 503 error mesage. here is my class following by app engine endpoint class. I appriciat if you can tell me where is the problem:

```
    package com.example.placeits;


import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;
import com.google.appengine.datanucleus.annotations.Unowned;





@PersistenceCapable
public class PlaceIt {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;
    @Persistent
    private String title;
    @Persistent
    private double longit;
    @Persistent
    private double latit;
    @Persistent
    private String description;
    @Persistent
    private int onSchedule;
    @Persistent
    private String status;
    @Persistent
    private int schedule=0;
    @Persistent
    private String cat0;
    @Persistent
    private String cat1;
    @Persistent
    private String cat2;
    @Persistent
    private Boolean iscategory;


    @Persistent
     @Unowned
    private User userName;


    public String getCat0() {
        return cat0;
    }
    public void setCat0(String cat0) {
        this.cat0 = cat0;
    }
    public String getCat1() {
        return cat1;
    }
    public void setCat1(String cat1) {
        this.cat1 = cat1;
    }
    public String getCat2() {
        return cat2;
    }
    public void setCat2(String cat2) {
        this.cat2 = cat2;
    }
    public void palceit()
    {
        id = getId();
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public double getLongit() {
        return longit;
    }
    public void setLongit(double longit) {
        this.longit = longit;
    }
    public double getLatit() {
        return latit;
    }
    public void setLatit(double latit) {
        this.latit = latit;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public int getOnSchedule() {
        return onSchedule;
    }
    public void setOnSchedule(int l) {
        this.onSchedule = l;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public int getSchedule() {
        return schedule;
    }
    public void setSchedule(int schedule) {
        this.schedule = schedule;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName.getUsername();
    }

    public void setUserName(String name) {
        userName = new User();
        userName.setUsername(name);
    }
    public Boolean getIscategory() {
        return iscategory;
    }
    public void setIscategory(Boolean iscategory) {
        this.iscategory = iscategory;
    }


}
```

And the app engine class is:

```
package com.example.placeits;

import com.example.placeits.PMF;

import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiNamespace;
import com.google.api.server.spi.response.CollectionResponse;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Cursor;
import com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.JDOCursorHelper;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityExistsException;
import javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException;
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManager;
import javax.jdo.Query;

@Api(name = "placeitendpoint", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "example.com", ownerName = "example.com", packagePath = "placeits"))
public class PlaceItEndpoint {
    /**
     * This method gets the entity having username. It uses HTTP GET method.
     *
     * @param username.
     * @return placeitlist.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "getPlaceItForUser")
    public List<PlaceIt> getPlaceItForUser(@Named("username") String username,
            @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {
        PersistenceManager mgr = null;

        List<PlaceIt> execute = null;

        try {
            mgr = getPersistenceManager();
            Query query = mgr.newQuery(PlaceIt.class);
            query.setFilter("userName ==" +username);


            execute = (List<PlaceIt>) query.execute();


            // Tight loop for fetching all entities from datastore and accomodate
            // for lazy fetch.
            for (PlaceIt obj : execute)
                ;
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }

        return execute;
    }
    /**
     * This method lists all the entities inserted in datastore.
     * It uses HTTP GET method and paging support.
     *
     * @return A CollectionResponse class containing the list of all entities
     * persisted and a cursor to the next page.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
    @ApiMethod(name = "listPlaceIt")
    public CollectionResponse<PlaceIt> listPlaceIt(
            @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
            @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {

        PersistenceManager mgr = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        List<PlaceIt> execute = null;

        try {
            mgr = getPersistenceManager();
            Query query = mgr.newQuery(PlaceIt.class);
            if (cursorString != null && cursorString != "") {
                cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
                HashMap<String, Object> extensionMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                extensionMap.put(JDOCursorHelper.CURSOR_EXTENSION, cursor);
                query.setExtensions(extensionMap);
            }

            if (limit != null) {
                query.setRange(0, limit);
            }

            execute = (List<PlaceIt>) query.execute();
            cursor = JDOCursorHelper.getCursor(execute);
            if (cursor != null)
                cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();

            // Tight loop for fetching all entities from datastore and accomodate
            // for lazy fetch.
            for (PlaceIt obj : execute)
                ;
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }

        return CollectionResponse.<PlaceIt> builder().setItems(execute)
                .setNextPageToken(cursorString).build();
    }

    /**
     * This method gets the entity having primary key id. It uses HTTP GET method.
     *
     * @param id the primary key of the java bean.
     * @return The entity with primary key id.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "getPlaceIt")
    public PlaceIt getPlaceIt(@Named("id") Long id) {
        PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
        PlaceIt placeit = null;
        try {
            placeit = mgr.getObjectById(PlaceIt.class, id);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return placeit;
    }

    /**
     * This inserts a new entity into App Engine datastore. If the entity already
     * exists in the datastore, an exception is thrown.
     * It uses HTTP POST method.
     *
     * @param placeit the entity to be inserted.
     * @return The inserted entity.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "insertPlaceIt")
    public PlaceIt insertPlaceIt(PlaceIt placeit) {
        PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
        try {
            if (containsPlaceIt(placeit)) {
                throw new EntityExistsException("Object already exists");
            }
            mgr.makePersistent(placeit);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return placeit;
    }

    /**
     * This method is used for updating an existing entity. If the entity does not
     * exist in the datastore, an exception is thrown.
     * It uses HTTP PUT method.
     *
     * @param placeit the entity to be updated.
     * @return The updated entity.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "updatePlaceIt")
    public PlaceIt updatePlaceIt(PlaceIt placeit) {
        PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
        try {
            if (!containsPlaceIt(placeit)) {
                throw new EntityNotFoundException("Object does not exist");
            }
            mgr.makePersistent(placeit);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return placeit;
    }

    /**
     * This method removes the entity with primary key id.
     * It uses HTTP DELETE method.
     *
     * @param id the primary key of the entity to be deleted.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "removePlaceIt")
    public void removePlaceIt(@Named("id") Long id) {
        PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
        try {
            PlaceIt placeit = mgr.getObjectById(PlaceIt.class, id);
            mgr.deletePersistent(placeit);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
    }

    private boolean containsPlaceIt(PlaceIt placeit) {
        PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
        boolean contains = true;
        try {
            mgr.getObjectById(PlaceIt.class, placeit.getId());
        } catch (javax.jdo.JDOObjectNotFoundException ex) {
            contains = false;
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return contains;
    }

    private static PersistenceManager getPersistenceManager() {
        return PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    }

}
```

Comment: Most likely, that method is generating an exception. Add some debug statements to find out what the problem is.

Comment: I already add all sorts of debugging statements, but I cannot find the error.

Comment: Get the value of "CollectionResponse.<PlaceIt> builder().setItems(execute)
                .setNextPageToken(cursorString).build();". Add a log/print and see whether the this expression is generating an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I had  this problem  because  Eclipse AGE generates  the listmethod  as POST, then I care  that method doing it  a  Get,  then the client does not need send  any post argument.  That work for me. Some like this:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "listPlaceIt",httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
public CollectionResponse<PlaceIt> listPlaceIt(
        @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
        @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {
 }
```